# Modx revo.Как можно настроить плагин gallery для работы в нескольких контекстах?

Tags: modx, gallery, revo

Всем привет.
Есть сайт на `modx revo`,установлен babel,сделан 1 дополнительный контекст(en).
Есть страничка на которой есть вывод gallery,в случае дефолтного контекста(web) все фотки выводятся отлично,но если открыть перевод ресурса в другом контексте фото не грузится.

Как я понял все дело в путях к файлам с фотографиями:

1. вот путь в контексте `web`:

   ```
   /assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=web&w=57&h=57&zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F41.jpg
   ```
2. а вот путь в контексте `eng` :

   ```
    /assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=eng&w=57&h=57&zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2Fen%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F41.jpg
   ```

Обратим внимание на конец ссылки:

1. `%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F41.jpg`
2. `%2Fen%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F41.jpg`

В `en` контексте он подписывает - `%2Fen` (ну или /en)

Хочу спросить,есть ли решение настройки gallery для 2 и более контекстов? Если есть то как это реализовать?

**Обновление**

Можно конечно и просто replace добавить:

```
<li>
    <a class="thumb" name="[[+name]]" href="[[+image:replace=`%2Fen%2F==%2F`]]" title="[[+name]]">
        <img src="[[+thumbnail:replace=`%2Fen%2F==%2F`]]" alt="[[+name]]" />
    </a>

</li>
```

Но это топорный вариант. Хотелось бы все по уму)

Вот такой вот способ тоже можно заюзать в главном снипgете Gallery строка 131... правим вот на это:

```
$itemArray['thumbnail'] = str_replace(array('%2Fen%2F'),'',$item->get('thumbnail',$thumbProperties)); $itemArray['image'] = str_replace(array('%2Fen%2F'),'',$item->get('image',$imageProperties));
```

В принципе это тот же самый реплейс, только уже внутри плагина.

Answer (score 2):

```
$itemArray['thumbnail'] = str_replace(array('%2F'.($modx->context->get('key')).'%2F'),'',$item->get('thumbnail',$thumbProperties)); $itemArray['image'] = str_replace(array('%2F'.($modx->context->get('key')).'%2F'),'',$item->get('image',$imageProperties));
```

или же создать сниппет getContextKey

```
return $modx->context->get('key');
```

и вызывать в фильтре

> [`[+image:replace=`%2F`[[getContextKey]]%2F==%2F`]`]